# Why is my RDS mysql slow query log full of server restarts?

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds, performance, slow-log

One of my RDS mysql databases is giving me warnings about the slow query logs taking up significant space.

The logs are rotated once an hour, and contain a dozen repetitions of:

```
/rdsdbbin/mysql/bin/mysqld, Version: 5.6.13-log (MySQL Community Server (GPL)). started with:
Tcp port: 3306  Unix socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
Time                 Id Command    Argument
```

What could be causing this?

Comment: I don't think it's restart. When RDS rotates logs it runs FLUSH LOGS

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not cause for concern.

MySQL writes a new header to the file each time the logs are flushed.  Presumably this is just in case you rotated the log file, so the new file will have a header... but it doesn't actually check whether it's a new file or not.  The server does not have to restart to write this entry, so it doesn't mean the server is necessarily restarting.

The `rdsadmin` user you see in the processlist appears to be the supervisory connection that Amazon uses to monitor and manage each instance.  Something -- presumably that connection -- periodically rotates the log files, most likely with some variant of `FLUSH LOGS;`.  It sounds like the flush occurs more often than the rotate, which would exactly explain what you're seeing.

```
mysql> SHOW STATUS LIKE 'uptime';
```

This will give you the actual uptime of the instance in seconds.  If that value is high, this is just the server writing a new header when the logs are being flushed to disk.

Comment: It's a bit of a concern because we are getting warnings that the slow query log is using > 20% of our allocated space.  RDS does eventually purge the logs, so it doesn't cause problems, but I would like to deal with it if possible.

Comment: i agree this is a space concern, but i believe this answers your question above

Answer (score 0):

Usually slow log should not grow .. if it keeps on growing then you must optimize queries and their performance add indexes wherever possible change datatypes of a table.

You can try disabling `log_queries_not_using_indexes` variable in `db_parameter` this entry will log all queries those are not using indexes.

You can specify db_parameter of `log_output` to TABLE

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_LogAccess.Concepts.MySQL.html